# Allow file access only if they belong to a published post/page in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, file, plugins, attachment

I need to know if there is a plugin that limits access to uploaded files based on the status of the post/page they are related to.

In other words, when I upload an image into a post but the post is not published, I need WordPress to not allow access to that image until I'm switching the post to Published.

I can code this myself so please let me know if there is a plugin already so I can save time.

Comment: I am sorry, but I might understood wrong , you need a URL restriction ? Or just not show the image ? (who will see the image if they can not see the post ? )

Comment: I have document files with names that could be guessed. What I need is to be able to upload them and attach to post and only then to be accesible.

Answer (score 1):

well, I do not know of any specific plugin that will do that , but what you will need to do is actually change the `.htaccess` direct access file permissions in order to achieve URL restrictions.

There is a very nice article written by Stephan Harris that treats this issue in wordpress with several methods .

http://www.stephenharris.info/2012/restricting-direct-access-to-files-in-wordpress/

In his article, Stephan Harris mentioned those method to prevent direct access . 
I still find it difficult to imagine a case where this will be needed on a published / not published basis .

But still - you can easily check for post-status (with [get_post_status()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_status) )and apply it in his script / methods to achieve what you want .
look in particular at the method where he redirects ALL the (IMAGE) request to go through the index.php - there you can easily insert a permission check.

A second method that you can apply is to CHANGE the upload folder , thus making it more difficult for people to "guess" , as you said, the URL. 
That can be done on a post-by-post basis (every post different folder) or by a random string .

you can do that by a variety of ways, one of which is described here :

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_upload_dir

or simply use a plugins like [THIS ONE](http://www.semiologic.com/software/uploads-folder/) that will give a folder name based on a post title . which is unknown to the non-authorized user until it is published.)